# Sending email from another Outlook account

Tags: python, windows, email, outlook, account

I'm trying to send an email from another Outlook account by setting the `SendUsingAccount` property.

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
accounts = outlook.Session.Accounts

for account in accounts:
    if account.SmtpAddress == 'sender@example.com': break

print(account.SmtpAddress, type(account))
#sender@example.com <class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'>

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'recipient@example.com'
mail.SendUsingAccount = account
mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>HTML Message body</h2>'
mail.Send()
```

But it still sends the email from my own account `myaccount@example.com` in instead of from `sender@example.com`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

`mail.SendUsingAccount = account`

with

`mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, account))`

works. If someone could explain...